# ipywidgets button onclick event is not raising the onclick method

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipywidgets

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
output = widgets.Output()

display(button, output)

def on_button_clicked():
    print("button clicked")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

The button shows up.. but when I click on the button, I expect to see the message "button clicked" to show up.  But that's not happening.

Is there something I'm missing here?
I am using vscode to run my jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass the button `b` in the definition of your `on_button_clicked` function. See examples in the doc [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.6.2/examples/Widget%20Events.html) and code below:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
output = widgets.Output()

display(button, output)

def on_button_clicked(b):
  with output:
    print("button clicked")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

And the output gives:

[image]